# Bootstrap WP модальное окно + карусель внутри него

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap

Есть код

Используется слайдер slick

```html
<?php if ($gallery_company) : ?>

<div id="TTEST" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:80%">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
          <span aria-hidden="true">
          <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">






        <div class="row b-page__part">
          <div class="col-xs-12">

            <div class="b-activity__slider b-activity__slider--events">
              <?php foreach ($gallery_company as $object) : ?>
              <?php if (wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($object->ID))) : ?>
              <div class="b-slick__element">
                <div class="b-activity__event">

                  <div class="b-activity__event-wrapper">

                    <img type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TTEST" class="b-activity__event-photo" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($object->ID)); ?>" alt="text-logo" />



                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <?php endif; ?>
              <?php endforeach; ?>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>






      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>



<?php endif; ?>
```

В общем модальное окно а внутри слайдер, при открытие модального окна не отображаются слайды пока не нажмешь на перелистывание.
Подскажите что не так с кодом? что то мне подсказывает что js как то не так работает в модальных окнах bootstrap.

Я очень плохо знаю js, подскажите пожалуйста что мне нужно сделать?

Код слайдера

```html
$('.b-activity__slider--events').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        autoplay: false,
        arrows: true,
        dots: true,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            }
            // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
            // settings: "unslick"
            // instead of a settings object
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно костыль

```html
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) { $('.b-activity__slider--gallery').slick("setPosition", 0); });
```

Авось поможет кому